# How handle UTF-8 encoding error in libpq?

Tags: sql, c, database, postgresql, libpq

I have created this function to insert data into database:

```
void add_data_to_db(){
        const char *data[2][2] = {"2","e"};
        re = PQexecParams(connection,
                        "INSERT INTO test_table "\
                        "VALUES ($1, $2);",
                        2,NULL,data[2],NULL,NULL,0);
        if(PQresultStatus(re) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK){
                printf("%s\n", PQresultErrorMessage(re));
        }

        PQclear(re);
}
```

but when I run the program it prints :

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x80
```

as far as I know this problem occurs when we have null value adding to table but I have not.

Comment: `data[2]` (in the function call) looks unusual to me; this is past the end of that array

Comment: @DanielJour how can i mention the words or chars in array in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `const char *data[2]`, and the function call should have `data` rather than `data[2]`.

The error message means that PostgreSQL encountered bytes that are not part of a correctly encoded UTF-8 string.

Comment: I want to have an array of some strings, and then add them to database. if I can not create `data[n][n]` how can I do this?

Comment: Either `char data[2][2]` or `char *data[2]`, but not `char *data[2][2]`.

Comment: I changed the line of defining `data` to `const char data[2][2]` and instead of using `data[2]` in fifth parameter, I used `data` but it still errors during the compile.

Comment: Since the errors are unknown to me, I cannot advise.

Comment: now I have an array `char splitted_line[8][50];` and I used it have an error `note: expected ‘const char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[50]’` and a warning `warning: passing argument 5 of ‘PQexecParams’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   99 |    8,NULL, splitted_line,NULL,NULL,0);
`
thanks for helping.

Comment: Add a type cast.

Comment: would you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-exec.html) the fifth argument of `PQExecParams` should be `const char * const *paramValues` ... so a [pointer to constant pointers which point to constant `char`](https://cdecl.org/?q=const+char+*+const+*paramValues).  The documentation specifies that it should point to an array of the specified (in the third argument) length (2 here).

`data[2]` is the third element of the `data` array (whoops, it has only two elements!).

`data` would decay to a pointer to the first element; that is a pointer to an array of two pointers which each point to a string.  Exactly what you need.